# How to know the right crawled property

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am trying to map a crawled property to a managed property. My intension is to get data from a site column present in a particular site collection in search. 
When searching for crawled properties, I found more than one similar crawled property starting with 'ows_'. Is there a way to find, under which crawled property my target site column data is present.

Site Column Name: AssetId

Crawled Properties:
ows_AssetId
ows_intAssetId
ows_PrmEn_AD_intAssetId
ows_PrmEn_BA_intAssetId
ows_PrmEn_ES_intAssetId
ows_q_NMBR_intAssetId

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tool like this: http://spm.codeplex.com/

[image]

Get the Inernal Name and map that on the crawling.

**[UPDATE]**

Usually the pattern is (let's do for a text column):

ows_q_TEXT_INTERNALNAME

[image]

I got this pic from my Sharepoint On Line tenancy

Comment: Thanks Salvatore. But its still a guess work to find the right crawled property using internal name in my above example. Is there any other concrete way to find out the right crawled property?

Comment: @PradeepNulu I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks Salvatore :). In my case AssetId is of type Number. And I have 3 crawled properties matching the pattern - ows_AssetId, ows_intAssetId, ows_q_NMBR_intAssetId. So, I am not sure which one is the right one upfront. I did some testing by mapping each & every property and found that ows_AssetId is having the data for my Site column. This whole procedure is very tedious as I need to map around 200 properties.